# Getting the right width and height of a canvas element

Tags: html, canvas

I am having difficulties with setting the correct width and height of my canvas element.

I have a ball, that I'd like to bounce back whenever it hits a screen boundary by changing it's vertical velocity. It works, but instead of moving back as soon as it hits the edge of the screen, it goes on for   a couple of seconds and THEN moves back. I have these variables to determine the viewport's size:

```
var left = 0,
    right = canvas.width,
    top = 0,
    bottom = canvas.height;
```

If my ball's x or y positions are outside these boundaries, the velocity should be changed to a negative one. However, during my animation I console.log it's x position and by the time it reaches the right edge of the screen the value is around 600, which is really strange, since I'm on a 1366x768px monitor.

Also, it doesnt't fully reach the left screen edge, but bounces off like 50px from it.

Any ideas are really appreciated, because I've been stuck on this for quite some time.

You can see a working example here: http://codepen.io/gbnikolov/pen/puiwk

Comment: canvas.offsetHeight and canvas.offsetWidth might work

Comment: No, unfortunately they don't... You mean to assign them to right and bottom variables respectively, right?

Answer (score 1):

Update your draw to the following.

```
Ball.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
  ctx.save();
  // you've translated to the x and y position of the ball.
  ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
  ctx.rotate(this.rotation);
  ctx.scale(this.scaleX, this.scaleY);
  ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
  ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  ctx.strokeStyle = this.strokeColor;
  ctx.beginPath();
  // Draw at 0,0 since we are already translated to the x and y.
  ctx.arc(0, 0, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yqufox8x/)**

Your problem is in the draw method, you're translating the context and then making the arc at the x and y of the ball so if you translate to 20, 20 for example and then draw at 20,20 your ball is actually at 40,40.